# Monitor gone bad out of the blue

Tags: display

I wanted to ask what the reason could be for a monitor display/color going bad?

What causes it to behave like this *see picture*

Can it be fixed? can whatever piece of hardware that causes it, be replaced e.g soldered?

What I've also noticed is that when it goes bad, it often times then turns good again after a long 10 min or so.

[image: monitor]

Comment: Try taking a screenshot whilst it's like this. See what that looks like when you can see again. That will eliminate it being a software issue.

Comment: Check cables. If you can, try another monitor & cables to rule out the PC/GPU/cables.

Comment: Monitors are generally not serviceable inside (surface mount circuit boards). Try a substitute monitor and replace the existing one if necessary.

Comment: I will try another HDMI cable, but I doubt its the cables. I have used another monitor, however that monitor only has VGA and it does work. So I don't have another Monitor with DP or HDMI inputs. I think I will just have to buy another one. Its as @John said, monitors generally are not serviceable. I only had the monitor for like 3 years max.

Comment: Sorry for the bad news bro.

Comment: @Gantendo yeah, its really frustrating and I can't afford a new on the spot. At least, not the same one. And it went bad during a ranked League gameplay so you can imagine.

Comment: I have an old Acer monitor that has a similar behavior. When I turn it on, the image is garbled and it will often scroll fast. At some point, the monitor warms up enough for the image to become stable, at which the monitor is usable again until I power it off and it cools down. The monitor works great, except I have to wait a bit. I'm using it for my server, so the monitor doesn't have to be used often. its like this for 5 years now and still working. But this is not something you can fix. If it bothers you, replace the monitor.

Comment: @LPChip yeah, I already decided to buy another one. This time a Benq and its gonna be a LED. Too many LCDs go bad to easily.

Comment: @YvanTheComputerGuy "LED" monitors still use LCD for the actual display, it's just the backlight uses LEDs instead of CCFL tubes. Unless you mean OLED which does actually use organic LEDs for the actual display element. Anything that says VA, TFT or IPS are all still variants of LCD monitor. OLED monitors are still somewhat prohibitively expensive. Gotta love the marketing idiots who love to muddy the water to make it easy for you to buy the wrong thing.

Comment: @Mokubai Aaah, yeah, I did not know this info, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bad cables, or bad connections (of the cable socket on either end to the motherboard or display adapter board of the computer or display) are the common cause. Damaged pins on connectors are sometimes seen with abusive users.

The cable is easy, the others are generally not economically sensible to fix out of warranty, and odds of fixing them yourself with a soldering iron are quite low.

If there's another input (display) or output (computer) such as DisplayPort or DVI-D you *might* be able to use that with a cable adapter (or entirely different cable, if both sides have it) instead.